# Data augmentation with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, data-augmentation

About ImageDataGenerator. My code is

```
Train_Data,Test_Data = train_test_split(Main_Data,train_size=0.9,shuffle=True,random_state=42)
Train_Data.shape

Train_IMG_Generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                    rotation_range=25,
                                    shear_range=0.5,
                                    zoom_range=0.5,
                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    fill_mode="nearest",
                                    validation_split=0.1)
Test_IMG_Generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_set=Train_IMG_Generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=Train_Data,
                                   x_col='png',
                                   y_col='cat',
                                   seed=42,
                                   color_mode='rgb',
                                   class_mode='categorical',
                                   target_size=(128,128),
                                   subset='training')
#prepare validation set
validation_set=Train_IMG_Generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=Train_Data,
                                       x_col='png',
                                       y_col='cat',
                                       seed=42,
                                       color_mode='rgb',
                                       class_mode='categorical',
                                       target_size=(128,128),
                                       subset='validation')
Test_IMG_Set = Test_IMG_Generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=Test_Data,
                                                   x_col="png",
                                                   y_col="cat",
                                                   color_mode="rgb",
                                                   class_mode="categorical",
                                                   target_size=(128,128),
                                                   shuffle=False)
```

Is this data augmentation or simply preprocessing? Am I getting any new images? Before calling flow_from_dataframe function we have 8083 images in Train_Data vector and after calling it the amount of images is still 8083, i think. Or at least we get this output after generating the training set and validation set.

> "Found 7275 validated image filenames belonging to 3 classes.
> Found 808 validated image filenames belonging to 3 classes."

which in total is 8083.

Where should I specify the number of new images I want ?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is the generator  creates a new image in the sense that the augmentation is carried out on the image and that image is provided to the model as part of the training data. These images are not saved unless to taken the action to save them. Below is the code to generate a specified number of augmented images and save them to a specified directory with a specified prefix and in a specified image format. I will assume that a dataframe df exists and has 2 columns. The filename column contains the full paths to the image files. The labels column contains the class name associated with the image.

```
import shutil
total = 0
img_size=(128,128)
aug_dir=r'c:\Temp\aug_images' # directory in which to save the images
num_desired = 10 # set to the number of images you want to save for EACH class
gen=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=25,
                       shear_range=0.5,
                       zoom_range=0.5,
                       width_shift_range=0.2,
                       height_shift_range=0.2,
                       horizontal_flip=True) # Notice did not rescale the images
if os.path.isdir(aug_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(aug_dir) # if the directory exists remove it
os.mkdir(aug_dir) # create an empty fresh aug_dir
class_groups=df.groupby('labels') #makes a dataframe for each unique label(class)
for label in df['labels'].unique():
    aug_count = 0
    dir_path=os.path.join(aug_dir,label)
    os.mkdir(dir_path) # in aug_dir make a sub directory for each class
    class_df=class_groups.get_group(label) #get dataframe for the label
    aug_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe( class_df,
                                     x_col='filepaths',
                                     y_col=None, 
                                     target_size=img_size,
                                     class_mode=None, 
                                     batch_size=1, 
                                     shuffle=False, 
                                     save_to_dir=dir_path, 
                                     save_prefix='aug-', 
                                     color_mode='rgb',
                                     save_format='jpg') 
    while aug_count < num_desired:
        images=next(aug_gen)
        aug_count +=1
    total += aug_count
print ('Total augmented images generated = ', total)
```

When you run this you create a directory c:\Temp\aug_dir. This directory will contain sub directories, one for each class. Within each of these sub directories there will be 10 augmented images. Each image file has the prefix aug- and an extension jpg. Images will be 128 X 128 X 3. Pixel values will be in the range 0 to 255. I did not scale the augmented images so if you combine the original images with the augmented images as a new composite data set they all have the same pixel range. Now you can merge the augmented images with the original images to create a composite data set with the code below

```
filepaths=[]
labels=[]
classlist=os.listdir(aug_dir)
for klass in classlist:
    classpath= os.path.join(aug_dir, klass)
    flist=os.listdir(classpath)
    for f in flist:
        fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)
        filepaths.append(fpath)
        labels.append(klass)
Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths')
Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')
aug_df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)
composite_df=pd.concat([df, aug_df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print ('df length: ' , len(df), '  aug_df length: ', len(aug_df), '  length composite_df: ', len(composite_df))
```

Now you can use this composite data set for training